# SignalR's Client list is empty when I use non-Controller Class in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, signalr-hub

I have an ASP.NET Core Webservice and a Blazor client. When my method is triggered in a class (not a controller) in the webservice, I want to send my data to my clients.

When I use a controller, it works but in a regular class, I see the `clients.All` are empty even `OnConnectedAsync` is triggered (means connected)

As I understand, `HubContext` is not a singleton but transient. I tried many things but the connected clients list is empty.

In my `Startup`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddSignalR();
     services.InstallServicesInAssembly(Configuration);
    services.AddTransient<IGeneralStockMarketHandler, GeneralStockMarketHandler>();

    services.AddCors(options =>
    {
       options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
       {
         policy.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader();
        });
    });            
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
 app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
 app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
 {
    endpoints.MapHub<NotificationHub>("/notificationhub");
    endpoints.MapControllers();
 }); 
}
```

My hub:

```
public class NotificationHub : Hub
{
     public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Client has connected");
        return base.OnConnectedAsync();
     }

     public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
     {
        Console.WriteLine("Client has disconnected");
       return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
     }
}
```

My `GeneralStockMarketHandler` class which I injected `IHubContext`:

```
 public GeneralStockMarketHandler(IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext)
 {
   _hubContext = hubContext;            
 }

 private async void MyStockMarketHandler_OnDataReceived(StreamSnapshotResponseModel response)
 {
   await HandleStreamSnapshotResponse(response);
   await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("notification", response.Data);
 }
```

As you see above `_hubContext.Clients.All` is empty even a client has connected, so it does not send any client.

In my Blazor app, `Index.razor`:

```
@code {
    string url = "http://localhost:1580/notificationhub";    
    HubConnection _connection = null;
    bool isConnected = false;
    string connectionStatus = "Ready";


    private async Task ConnectToServer()
    {
        _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl(url)
            .Build();

        await _connection.StartAsync();
        isConnected = true;   
        connectionStatus = "Connected";

        _connection.Closed += async (s) =>
        {
            isConnected = false;
            connectionStatus = "Disconnected";
            await _connection.StartAsync();
            isConnected = true;
        };
            
        _connection.On<string>("notification", m =>
        {      
          connectionStatus = "I have data!";     
          StateHasChanged();
        });
    }
}
```

When my `HubContext` is injected into the controller, it works but when it is in a regular class, it does not work because the `clients.All` is empty. How can I solve this problem?

**UPDATE:**

I think, I found out the problem. In my installer, I create an instance from GeneralStockMarketHandler class and call a method which is StartToSubscribeAllStocksFromDb. I have to call this method once in the beginning

```
 services.AddScoped<IGeneralStockMarketHandler, GeneralStockMarketHandler>();    
 var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
 var stockMarketHandler serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IGeneralStockMarketHandler>();
 stockMarketHandler.StartToSubscribeAllStocksFromDb();
```

If I do not create an instance from GeneralStockMarketHandler class then I can get the connected clients.

I dont understand why it effects the logic. It is not singleton and I use it only one time

Comment: Could you please tell me how you use this GeneralStockMarketHandler class?  Besides, I suggest you could try to make some method inside the hub to use `Clients.All.SendAsync` method and call this method instead of directly use its client outside the method.

Comment: @BrandoZhang thank you for your message. I updated the question, please check it there. As you meant, the problem was from GeneralStockMarketHandler  and I was creating an instance of GeneralStockMarketHandler in the initializing time and it causes the problem. I need to call this method once when the service starts.

Comment: Do you put these codes at the startup.cs codes?  Since the startup.cs class will just called once. That means at that time, the NotificationHub will just inject at that time and will never change. This is the reason why your client is null. Could you please tell me why you call this GeneralStockMarketHandler once at the startup.cs?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem. The solution that seemed to me was that I defined a class called HubClientInfo and added it as a Singleton to the project services in the method
This class is defined as follows::

```
public interface IHubClientInfo
{
  List<IClientProxy> Clients {  set; get; }
  void Add(IClientProxy Client);
  void Remove(IClientProxy Client);
}
```

In my hub, I injected the service of this class, and in the OnConnectedAsync method, I called the Add method of my class, and in the OnDisconnectedAsync method, I called the Remove method of my class. Finally, wherever I need to broadcast a message to my client, I inject the HubClientInfo service and send the message in this way.

```
foreach(var Client in _HubClientInfo.Clients)
   await Client.SendAsync("SendMessage", "a", "b");
```